# Something is undefined, and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ecmascript-5

I'm working on a project that combines a few different loves of mine. D&D, Spreadsheets (Google) and code.

I have this custom function that I am working on, that basically should automatically look up this table:

```
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   d100   |                                                                               Result                                                                               |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 01 - 60  | The item communicates by transmitting emotion to the creating carrying or wielding it.                                                                             |
| 61 - 90  | The item can speak, read, and understand one or more Languages.                                                                                                    |
| 91 - 100 | The item can speak, read, and understand one or more Languages. In addition, the item can communicate telepathically with any character that carries or wields it. |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is the script that I have so far:

```
function communication(max){
  for (var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max) + 1); 60 > roll; )
  return "The item communicates by transmitting emotion to the creating carrying or wielding it.";
  for (; 90 > max; )
    return "The item can speak, read, and understand one or more Languages.";
  for (; 100 > max; )
    return "The item can speak, read, and understand one or more Languages. In addition, the item can communicate telepathically with any character that carries or wields it.";
  if (typeof something === "undefined") {
    Logger.log("something is undefined");
    Logger.log(roll)
  }
}
```

It works, mostly. However on occasion it throws out a undefined error, and I can't figure out why.

> [18-11-02 21:12:50:909 GMT] something is undefined
>   [18-11-02 21:12:50:910 GMT] 93.0
>   [18-11-02 21:12:50:910 GMT] undefined

I know that the last undefined is because I'm not returning the roll variable, but the issue happens even with that returned.
93 is less than 100, and greater than 91 and so that should return:

> The item can speak, read, and understand one or more Languages. In
>   addition, the item can communicate telepathically with any character
>   that carries or wields it.

Anyone able to shed some light on it?

Comment: `for (; 90 > max; )`  you might be looking for `if` here.. eg. `if (max > 90)` etc.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: Why are you using for statements like that?

Comment: Where are you defining something in the first place? Of course it will be undefined if you never define it in the scope.

Comment: You guys put me on the right track. Have a working answer and will post it below as the answer. Thanks, knew I was being daft!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a full rewrite of this code. You need to stop using `for` statements in place of `if`.

```
function c(max) {
 var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max) + 1)
 if (roll <= 60)
    return "The item communicates by transmitting emotion to the creating carrying or wielding it.";
 else if (roll <= 90)
    return "The item can speak, read, and understand one or more Languages.";
 else if (roll <= 100)
    return "The item can speak, read, and understand one or more Languages. In addition, the item can communicate telepathically with any character that carries or wields it.";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I was being silly and using for statements in a bad way.

This achieves what I am aiming for:

```
function communication(max) {
  var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max) + 1);
  if (60 > roll)
    return "The item communicates by transmitting emotion to the creating carrying or wielding it.";
  return 90 > roll
    ? "The item can speak, read, and understand one or more Languages."
    : 100 > roll
      ? "The item can speak, read, and understand one or more Languages. In addition, the item can communicate telepathically with any character that carries or wields it."
      : void 0;
}
```

Comment: If you look at @stewartmcgown answer, it's a lot easier to understand what's going on, although a slight bug I will point out in his answer.  Mixing the `if`'s here with a `ternary` just looks like your trying to make things harder for people to follow. :)